# Locate database entry based on ID from another database entry in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been digging around a little trying to figure out how I should locate the "tweet_id" in my #savedtweets table and then locate that same "tweet_id" in my #newtweets table from a controller, so far I'ved tried something like this;

### CONTROLLER

```
@stweet = Savedtweet.find(params[:id])
@newtweet = Newtweet.where(:tweet_id => @stweet.tweet_id)
@newtweet.status = 'new'
@newtweet.save
```

Basically I need to change the string "saved" in my Newtweets table to "new" based on the current Savedtweet ID. I just can't figure it out. If I do the following in console;

@stweet = Savedtweet.first
@newtweet = Newtweet.where(:tweet_id => @stweet.tweet_id)

It finds the right one. I've got to be close just not there yet. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

`Newtweet.find_by_tweet_id(@stweet.tweet_id).update_attribute(:status, 'new')`

The reason your code isn't working is because `Newtweet.where()` returns an array of objects. It should be `Newtweet.where().first`, though `Newtweet.find_by_tweet_id` is the preferred method.

Comment: Hey thanks! after few minutes I've figure this was working @newtweet = Newtweet.where(:tweet_id => @stweet.tweet_id).update_all(:status => 'new')... however I do see your approach much better than running through updating it all and stuff. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I've put it into production and it now stopped working. I don't get any errors in the log other then; ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/dashboards_controller/create"): .... not sure if that's related. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2419316 I'm afraid that's unrelated. I'd suggest posting a new question with further details to get more helpful feedback. The error tells me there is something wrong with your `routes.rb`.

Comment: Got it, just posted another question similar to find_by_tweet_id, thanks again for helping on this one.